# Numerically find energy eigenvalues of a large symbolic matrix in Mathematica for a given range

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

I have a 136x136 Hamiltonian (matrix) and need to find its eigenvalues.

It cannot be solved analytically with Eigenvalues[H] as it is required to solve a 136th order polynomial.

I need to solve it numerically by replacing the symbolic terms with values before computing its eigenvalues. However, it needs to be plotted for a range of values of the symbolic term for example -1 < x < 1.

Is there a method to numerically solve and plot a range of values?

```
{
 {10.1358 - 6.72029 x, 0., 0.},...
 {0., 10.1358 - 6.72029 x, 0.},
 {0., 0., 10.1358 - 6.72029 x},
 {0., 0., 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.},
 {0., 0.204252, 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.267429}
...
```

Corner of matrix as example. Matrix is real and symmetric.